# Calling Rails update Method via Inline Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I was putting together a quick inline editing feature in my first Rails app and just as I was getting it working it occurred to me that I may be violating RESTful principles. The edit updated an image name. To do so, it submits, via `PUT` to `Image#update` and passes the new modified name as `image[name]`.

The database gets updated properly, but I need that value back so that my markup can reflect the name change. To do that, I was calling `/images/:id.json`, but that got me wondering whether a PUT request can "validly" (in that RESTful sort of way) return a value like this.

Thoughts?

**Update:** For whatever it's worth, I'm using jQuery and the jEditable plugin to do the inline editing. Here's my jEditable code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('h2').editable(
    '/images/' + $('#image-id').val() + '.json',
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      name:   'image[name]',
      submitdata: { authenticity_token: $('#auth-token').val() },
      submit: 'Save',
      cancel: 'Cancel'
    }
  );
})
```

And my `Image#update` method as it exists right now:

```
def update
  @image = Image.find( params[:id] )
  if @image.update_attributes( params[:image] )
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated image."

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @image }
      format.json { render :json => @image.to_json }
    end
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: I take it your main concern is that the response from your update JSON is the image and not just a `head :ok`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. After I update the image name, I need to return the new name so that I can display it. If I return nothing, jEditable seems to just empty the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is just that your update method with JSON provide a response body and not just a `200 OK` (Rails's `head :ok`) then I don't think you need to be worried. The default response is `200 OK` so the only difference between what you're doing and what Rails does by default (in its scaffolds) is that you're also including a response body. As far as I can tell proper REST etiquette only requires that you return a `200 OK` and doesn't care about the response body, which is in line with what you're doing.

Beyond that all your code looks excellent.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to get overly pedantic or puritanical about being RESTful, but I'd like to shoot for purity where I can and scale back where I have to.